# Things to include or exclude from a roll2o LFG post?

Tags: roll20, finding-other-players

I'm trying to run a roll20 Pathfinder game and I feel like my posting is getting very little attention or interest.

Here's the ad I posted:

> Magic as you would know it has been gone for eons, you live in a near utopia guarded and guided by The Consciousness, a robotic hive mind of public servants although this game wont be set there. You've been selected to investigate an enigma of terrible consequence, a house has appeared in a once empty lot, at least The Consciousness said so. Recorded memory holds that the house has always been there; how a late century Victorian could ever still be standing is anyone's guess. Much to your leader's chagrin magic works but all tech shuts off as soon as it crosses the threshold. From simply observing the gigantic foyer, its clear the house is much bigger on the inside. How long can you roam the halls before you fall victim to its denizens?
>
> Body, psychological, and existential horror. The overarching challenge will be maintaining your limited resources.
>
> Meta Notes:
>
> All casting is replaced with Spheres of Power/Might
>
> 5th level start 20 PB with 3000 gp (Survival supplies will be provided by the state)
>
> Automatic Bonus Progression
>
> No alignments, replaced with purely flavor "Values and Principles"
>
> No gods, or planes (though summons still work)
>
> Magic items other than potions and scrolls are barred from purchase but cost 1/3 base price.
>
> This game should run about 10 sessions with 1-2 levels per session with a
> perspective level cap of 15-18, after that I'll come up with a new game within the same continuity.

I tagged this as *Puzzles, Dungeon, SoP (spheres of power), Horror*.

Was I too vague in the interest of keeping up the mystery? Is my scope too limited? Is there something I'm just missing?

What I'm trying to run is an amorphous super dungeon with heavy inspiration from the book House of Leaves.

I found this post about [game pitches](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/what-makes-a-good-pitch-for-a-new-game) slightly helpful but it doesn't give any advice on the cold pitch style.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're *not* looking to run a live-and-in-person tabletop game. Is that correct?

Comment: It would be live but not in person, is there some way i can make that more clear?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. While I agree with the moderator that as written the question is *largely* opinion-based, I think the site may be able to address *your* issue directly (and, in doing so, help others). While it might be a better topic for a forum, a question that asks *How can I punch up my campaign ad?* then posting the ad so experts in advertising to gamers can advise you on how to improve it *may* be okay. (Keep links to the ad out of your question, though, so it's clear that you're looking to the site for help not for players!) Have fun and good luck.

Comment: @doppelgreener Take a look at my comment above and see if I'm on the right track. I'm not entirely sure that's appropriate advice, so, please, delete the comment if it ain't. Thanks.

Comment: I thought posting the actual ad itself might be a faux paux because it would be too specific to my game. so i tried to frame my question around it, but in your words it makes a lot more sense, i'll see what dop says before i make a move though

Comment: Making your question super specific to your own situation, game, ad, etc is always beneficial. The best way to get yourself helped, and thus help others, is ironically to just be a bit selfish here and look out for your own specific scenario. Go ahead and post your ad content. We can't advise on general arbitrary guidelines for any ad ever.

Comment: Ok so i updated the question to include the pitch, should i add any more specifics to help find an answer?

Comment: I've reopened. The community can guide you from here (and may put this back on hold temporarily whilst they do, if it's considered necessary).

Comment: There are a bunch of typos in the summary, but otherwise it seems fine. (I'd post this as a regular answer but it seems incomplete - and I'm not sure what else I can add.)

Comment: Ran the ad through a better word processor and fixed some things while changing the sentence structure.  @V2Blast if you would like to make your own edits on the ad I would be eternally grateful, proper grammar isn't my strong suit. Although from the quality of other ads I doubt it's the core problem.